# mongodb query return single element in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

```
{People:"1","Location":"US","Name":[{"first":"Tom","last":"Brady"},
{"first":"Jack","last":"Sparrow"},{"first":"Haha","last":"OhOh"}]}
```

I have some data in MongoDB, the data structure is like this, how Can I search "Tom" and only return

```
 {People:"1","Location":"US","Name":[{"first":"Tom","last":"Brady"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

`db.collectionName.find({"Name.first": "Tom"}, {_id: 0, People: 1, Location: 1, "Name.$": 1});`